# Convert date time to time only

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have date string like this:-
`2016-12-20T15:26:21+11:00`

What kind of `DateFormatter` (or else) will it required so that I can get the time in device's current time zone.

Comment: What kind of date formatter have you tried?

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a

Comment: That has a date in it, I thought you wanted the time only?

Comment: Yes, only time. But in device's time zone. I don't want to use:- `componentsSeparatedBy` method

Comment: You don't need to do that, just use the time components in the format string.

Comment: if you pass this date then what time you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input is ISO8601, a suitable solution is `DateFormatter`. Without specific settings for `locale` and `timeZone` the formatter considers the current locale and time zone.

```
let dateString = "2016-12-20T15:26:21+11:00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
let date = formatter.date(from:dateString)
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
formatter.dateStyle = .none
print(formatter.string(from: date!))
```

Comment: Could you please help me to find the format for this: 2019-05-23T10:21:20.044826-04:00

Comment: @pkc456 `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Sxxx`, please see https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Pattern_Examples

Comment: the date is returning nil for `2019-11-20T00:00:00-05:00` ? I checked the link too but not able to find the format. Can you please share teh date formatter for mentioned date string?

Comment: @pkc456 This is the same format as in my answer. Please visit the link above and learn to distinguish the format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for converting date string to only time

```
       let sourceDateString = "2016-12-20T15:26:21+11:00"
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        let date = formatter.date(from: sourceDateString)
        print("\(date)")

        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

        let strDate = formatter.string(from: date!)
        print(strDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern way to do it. You can try it in a playground:

```
let dateString = "2016-12-20T15:26:21+11:00"

// First use an ISO8601 Date formatter to turn the string into a date.

let inputFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = inputFormatter.date(from: dateString)! // Force unwrapping as this is a demo - you should be more careful.

// Now use a normal DateFormatter set to your current locale, turn of the date display, and use a short Time display style:

let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.locale = Locale.current
outputFormatter.dateStyle = .none
outputFormatter.timeStyle = .short

let display = outputFormatter.string(from: date)

// As I'm in the UK and the simulator local is US, I get "4:26 AM"
// Your result will be different.
```